# Syllable — Phonetic Online List/Dictionary with word examples

Tags: pronunciation, dictionaries, resources, ipa

Is there a homepage or online tool that gives you a list of, let's say, the 2000 most common syllables sorted by their international phonetic alphabet spelling?
(e.g. /sɜː(r)/ = the first syllable from the word circle which is the same as for circus)
and gives some examples next to it like:

sɜː(r) For example: circle, circus, ...

**I'm not looking for a usual dictionary with IPA characters.**

**Neither am I looking for a phonetic dictionary that lists several thousand words ordered by spelling.**

Do you know a syllable-based online webpage that lists the most-used prefixes and suffixes in an alphabetic IPA spelling order (and may give some word examples in brackets next to the listed syllable)?

Comment: What you're looking for is a [*phonetic dictionary*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_dictionary), which is a dictionary organized by the way words *sound*. The linked Wikipedia article points to a selection of online phonetic dictionaries, but if they don't have the features you need, you could always literally [Google for phonetic dictionary](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=phonetic+dictionary#q=phonetic+dictionary).  FYI, asking for recommendations or polling for opinions is discouraged on StackExchange sites generally.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources

Comment: It's more then just a "phonetic dictionary" what I'am looking for. It should be a list which do not  mention each (of more then 20'000) word but rather gives you a list with the 100-1000 most used syllables in IPA (and at the right side some example words). I don't think such a powerful for english learners (my level is between B2 and C1) does already exist. I guess it's not a question you will find an answer easily just by using Google.

Comment: One of the reasons that I wrote my own dictionary software is for this very reason. I could find nothing that did quite what you were asking, but I wanted it.  It’s really useful to be able to do. I would think someone would have done this for the public at large by now.  BTW, the “phonetic” spellings in IPA in dictionaries are actually phonemic ones, and do not reflect local dialect difference of allophones. At best, you may get a US and UK version (as though there were but one of each).

Comment: **pronounciation**?

Comment: Suggesting migration to meta.

Comment: @tchrist The last I heard was as much as "the reason why is because," but now this blows my mind. ( "one of the reasons ... is for this very reason"). Very reasonable :)

Comment: Just for the record, if you very simply click to **google translate**, it now has a handy feature where it will speak most words.  Check it out.

Comment: Handling 1000 entries isn't a workload you'd usually balk at, @tchrist. I suspect you intend publishing. Fine idea.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for resources. But it's such a sensible request that I'm upvoting. I've been rewatching John John Deed, and he always puts justice above the law (except in his private life).

Comment: There is a formula in Whorf's _Language, Thought, and Reality_ for the English syllable; it produces something like 25,000 syllables, not all of which occur. I do have a list of the 5000 or so English monosyllabic words (and 1½-syllable words like _water_), sorted by pronunciation, if you're interested.

Comment: @John Lawler Yes, this would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

A tentative answer - I'm not a phonetician or computational linguist. I would be interested in a more authoritative response.

You can get this information from the CELEX corpus. There is a web interface for this here: http://celex.mpi.nl

You can extract a list of all (or some) syllables, with their frequency (per million or raw) in the corpus. You can also get syllable information for words in the corpus and use this to construct your own frequencies. This has the advantage of also giving access to examples. I wrote some quick code to do this a while ago which we didn't in the end use. It could be (and I'm sure has been) substantially improved upon. Here is one row from the resulting data:

syllable (in the notation that CELEX uses: hIm
frequency:53007 
typical consonant vowel structure:CVC
examples: him   himself hymn    hymnal  hymnals